# Is it possible via the Google Drive API to email a link to a spreadsheet that is editable without logging in to a Google Account?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to be able to send an email to someone via the Drive API containing a link that will allow them to edit a spreadsheet on Google Docs without requiring them to sign in with or register for a Google account.

My first attempt (in Scala, using the Java client):

```
  def share1(driveService: Drive, file: File, emailOfPersonToShareWith : String, emailMessage: String) = {

    val writerPermission = new Permission()
      .setType("user")
      .setRole("writer")
      .setValue(emailOfPersonToShareWith)

    val insert = driveService.permissions().insert(file.getId, writerPermission)
    insert.setSendNotificationEmails(true)
    insert.setEmailMessage(emailMessage)

    insert.execute()
}
```

This sends a notification email, but the link that gets sent allows the recipient to view the spreadsheet without logging in, but does not allow them to edit it without logging in.

It appears to be possible to get a link with the desired behaviour by making the document editable to anyone with the link:

```
  def share2(driveService: Drive, file: File, emailOfPersonToShareWith : String, emailMessage: String) = {

    val editableByAnyone = new Permission()
      .setType("anyone")
      .setRole("writer")
      .setWithLink(true)

    val insert = driveService.permissions().insert(file.getId, editableByAnyone)
    insert.execute()

    file.getAlternateLink //this link now has the desired behaviour

  }
```

But I am unable to send a notification email in this case as that option is only available when sharing with users or groups. If, after making the document editable to anyone with the link, I then call my original share1 method to set the 'writer' permission for 'emailOfPersonToShareWith', the link that gets emailed is still not editable without logging in. The emailed link contains an "invite" URL parameter which seems to triggers this behaviour.

Is there any way to send someone a notification email via the SDK that contains a link that is editable without logging in without making the document editable to anyone with the link? Failing that, is there any way to send this email via the SDK if I do mark the document as editable to anyone with the link?

Comment: In the case of a document that is accessible to anyone with the link, there is no way you can send a Drive API notification email as you do not specify the email.. the link is accessible to "anyone".

How ever what you can do, is send your own personnalised mail, after you have shared the document with your share2 function.

Comment: In python, this is what I use to send personnalized notification emails: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail